# Image on Glossary page

Tags: graphics, glossaries

**Problem:** How to insert an image into glossaries (not in a single glossary entry).

Various entries refer to parts of the image. It should appear on the top of one of pages of Glossary (preferably second page).

I tried to use `\newcommand` but unfortunately the image does not appear in glossaries.

```
\newcommand\fovimage{\begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth} 
        \input{../images/FOV-Swath.pdf_tex}
        \caption{Visualization of Field of View and swath width of the satellite}
        \label{fig:fov-swath}
\end{figure}}

\newglossaryentry{fov}{%
    name        =   {Field of View},%
    description =   {(FOV) (see \autoref{fig:fov-swath})is ... \fovimage}
}
```

**My example code:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nopostdot]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newglossaryentry{fov}{%
    name        =   {Field of View},%
    description =   {(FOV) (see \autoref{fig:fov-swath})%
    is the conical region that intersects the visible...}
}

\begin{document}

Some camera has some \gls{fov} that allows to...

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

**The image code:**

```
\begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth} 
        \input{../images/FOV-Swath.pdf_tex}
        \caption{Visualization of Field of View and swath width of the satellite}
        \label{fig:fov-swath}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Your setup does not make use of `\fovimage`. One way is to use `\setglossarypreamble{\floatimage}`, but it can't be guaranteed that the image appears on the second page of the glossary this way!

Comment: Thank you, this works as intended. The image shows at the top of the second page. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can post a self - answer, if you like ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `\setglossarypreamble{content}`

Image is shown on the second page if `[t]` is used and changing image positioning to `[h]` sets it just below the `Glossary` header.

So the final code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nopostdot]{glossaries}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
    name        =   {Foo},%
    description =   {(Foo) (see Figure \ref{fig:foo})%
    \lipsum[1-10]}
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit \gls{foo} bar...

\newcommand\floatimage{
        \begin{figure}[t]
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[]{}
        \caption{Image caption}
        \label{fig:foo}
    \end{figure}
}

\setglossarypreamble{\floatimage}
\printglossary

\end{document}
```